# CherryPy Python error "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, server, cherrypy

Im trying to run a python Server using CherryPy for a WebSite but when I run it this error pops up.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 638, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 694, in _do_respond
    self.hooks.run('before_handler')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 95, in run
    self.run_hooks(iter(sorted(self[point])))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 117, in run_hooks
    hook()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.callback(**self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cptools.py", line 280, in _lock_session
    cherrypy.serving.session.acquire_lock()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py", line 550, in acquire_lock
    self.lock = zc.lockfile.LockFile(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/zc/lockfile/__init__.py", line 117, in __init__
    super(LockFile, self).__init__(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/zc/lockfile/__init__.py", line 87, in __init__
    fp = open(path, 'a+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/html/cncsessions\\/session-73ab2ecbe9bd50153b4f20828fcc08bff6e9cd6e.lock'
```

It's my first time using this module and I don't know what's wrong.
I'm using Ubuntu 22, Python 3.10.6

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your exact code that this is calling.

Judging by the Error you are trying to use Sessions.

The sessions are looking for
`/var/www/html/cncsessions`
To place the session files in

But it gives an error. It looks like the path might be wrong. There's a double backslash at the end there and a forward slash.
`\\/`

If you haven't given up on this/figured it out already I would try changing this path to just this
`/var/www/html/cncsessions`

Also be sure you do not store your session data in your web root. Looks like from that path you might be doing that! Anything in a webroot will be served via public webserver. There's little to no chance anyone would guess the file names though.